# how to insert value in input, with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I tried to do something like this -

```
$('#price').val(price);
```

price is 300, and it shows good on browser, in input field, but when I want to take it out and mail it with PHP, in $_POST['price'] it doesn't show up, How can I insert something in inputs value with JavaScript, so I can mail it? It seems this is not an insertion in value, but just a feature to display something, correct?

Comment: Does your price field have a name and not just an ID?

Comment: show us corresponding html code

Comment: And is the input field inside a `<form>` tag?

Comment: The input field has name, is inside <form> tags, it's POST, it's got unique ID and it's readonly.

Comment: <input type="text" style="color: green; width:268px;" readonly name="price" id="price" />

Comment: In your PHP print out somewhere your $_REQUEST variables to see what the server is receiving from the client. You can also verify what the client is sending to the server via using fiddler or firebug to look at the post request. If the value 300 is showing on the browser then it should be sent (there isn't a separate attribute for display).

Comment: Are you positive your input is somewhere inside a <form></form> element? Is it possible your form is closing before you have the <input>?

Comment: Hello, no, since there are many other input fields after that field and everything is fine. In firebug and Other source viewers, it doesn't show up value in the input field, should I add it in code, or javascript should add it on it's own? The price changes if I select other options, so I must insert the price with Javascript.

Comment: When I say look at it in firebug I meant have firebug open and click the network tab. Click persist. Then submit the form. You will see the POST request under URL. Open that and you will see Headers, Response, Cache, HTML, Params. Click on Params and make certain Price is in there.

Comment: Yes the price showed up there, but it doesn't show up in mail :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few possible reasons:

1) Your input field is not inside the form.
2) You are actually using a GET and not a POST.

Assuming that you can see the value updated in Firebug or Chrome's equivalent, it's gotta be one of those. Switch over to using $_REQUEST and see if that changes anything.

Comment: Thanks, you helped me solve the problem, since I misspeled the word "price" in defining the value, lol :)!

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this code can help you

```
document.getElementById('yorInputID').value = "Your Value";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your input for #price needs to also have a name "price"

```
<input id="price" value="price" />
```

From your question I'm assuming that this input is hidden -- and if that's the case I want to advise you not to rely on hidden fields + Javascript to provide you with security. It's so easily hackable I wouldn't even call it hacking.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the input is not "disabled" when the form submits.

if it's disabled the form don't send it.